# TYPO3 news list PID redirect to other link, with EXT: News System KEY: news VER: 2.2.1

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.1.x

Im running TYPO3 v. 6.1 with FLUID/EXTBASE.

I have setup the News plugin and have added the PID for the news list as ID 4 and it gives me this.
[Link 1](http://codem.dk/oevelser/) working fine but the link "Alle" is not activ, so if I want that to be activ the real link is this [Link 2](http://codem.dk/oevelser/itemCat/alle/) so my question is.

Where can i tell the TYPO3 setup, this if im going to a PID = 4 (codem.dk/oevelser/) then it need to rederict me to codem.dk/oevelser/itemCat/alle/ so i dont need to make changes in the Hmenu/Tmenu.. can I do this in "Web" -> "List" -> "Domain" or can i do it a better way ?

Comment: So basically you want to redirect "Link 1" to "Link 2"? You could use a .htaccess redirection or a redirection in Info > RealURL Management > Redirects.

Comment: I think Thomas wants to achieve the highlighting (and display of all posts) he gets with http://codem.dk/oevelser/itemCat/alle/, but with the URL http://codem.dk/oevelser/

Comment: Yes Urs (Y) thats what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are using the realurl extension on your site to make the URLs pretty. There is a [documented feature](http://wiki.typo3.org/Realurl/manual) called "valueDefault" which you may use to set your default category.